# how can I get every day of the month except Friday with Moment.js?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

Can someone help me ? I'm trying to get all the days of the month except Friday to disable all this days in a date picker but I can't figure out, how to proceed. I'm looking for the solution for a while now...

So I need an array of Moment to disable them in the date picker.
[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@y0c/react-datepicker) is the date picker.

Thank's for your time and sorry for my bad english !

Comment: you mean all Fridays or just one ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what's the datepicker you're using? Usually date pickers export a function that accepts the day and returns whether it's blocked or not.

Comment: @vamshikrishna I'm trying to get all the Fridays

Comment: @MatanBobi It is on react, I'm trying to elaborate an appointment component, the module that I use need a Moment in parameter to make these moments disabled.

Thanks for your help

Comment: @Ytech So you mean that you need an array of moment objects to disable?

Comment: @MatanBobi exactly ! Sorry if it wasn't clear ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without extending `moment` you can try:

```
let fridaysInMonth = [];

const monthDate = moment().startOf('month');
const daysInMonth = monthDate.daysInMonth();
for(let i=0; i< daysInMonth; i++){
  if (monthDate.day() === 5){
    const currFridayDate = moment(monthDate);
    fridaysInMonth.push(currFridayDate);
  }

  monthDate.add(1, 'day');
}
```

Or extend `moment` and use [moment-range](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range):

```
const month = moment();
const range = moment().range(moment(month).startOf('month'), moment(month).endOf('month'));
const days = range.by('days');
const fridaysInMonth = days.filter(currDay => currDay.day() === 5);
```

Comment: Thank's for your help !

Comment: @Ytech No problem. If you found it useful please mark it as an answer.